# Create categories manually in database

Tags: categories, database

I'm new in wordpress and trying insert some categories directly in Database, it's like:

```
wp_terms - insert register (Ex: ID:1, name: Cat 1
wp_terms - insert register (Ex: ID:2, name: Cat 1_1

wp_term_taxonomy - insert the relation (Ex: tid: 1, ttid: 1, parent: 0)
wp_term_taxonomy - insert the relation (Ex: tid: 2, ttid: 2, parent: 1)
```

In theory, I have a relation of hierarchy (dad and son), but the Wordpress cant show the relation in panel's list, like Categories.

Can someone help?
Tks.

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding your question but that is exactly what WordPress allows you to do with Categories.  You create a category, then create a second category and assign the first as a parent.

Comment: Yes, but when I create manually that example in database, the Wordpress just dont list in Categories panel

Comment: You’re most likely just missing some data/details.  Why are you manually creating the categories instead of just using the interface?

Comment: I am creating via script because it is a migration from another database, and it is outside the application